# awstats configuration with logresolvemerge and dates

Tags: apache-2.2, awstats

I'm trying to setup awstats with our current log naming schema.  Our logs are named like `/var/log/webservers/web07/2012-10/site.com/29-www` and all of the numbers are changed via cronolog.  The problem is that there is more than just `29-www`.  We also have things like `29-admin`.  I would like to combine all of these `DD-*` logs with awstats.  I have tried `LogFile="/var/awstats/tools/logresolvemerge.pl /var/log/webservers/web07/%YYYY-%MM/site.com/%DD-*"` but I'm getting this error:

`Error: Couldn't open server log file "/var/awstats/tools/logresolvemerge.pl /var/log/webservers/web07/2012-10/site.com/29-*" : No such file or directory`

So it looks like it's converting the symbols into the correct numbers.  Anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Also, I can successfully merge these files myself from the command line by doing `perl logresolvemerge.pl /var/log/webservers/web07/2012-10/site.com/29-* > newlog`

Comment: Some questions: is that path to `logresolvemerge.pl` correct?  Is it executable? Is the shebang line correct? Are the log files readable by the user that AWStats runs as?

Comment: Yes yes, how would I tell?, and yes

Comment: The first line is probably `#!/usr/bin/perl`.  That path should go to your `perl` installation.

Comment: When I issue the command myself it works just fine.  Are you saying I need to do `LogFile="perl /pathtoawstatstools/logresolvemerge.pl ...` ?

Comment: No, not if the shebang is correct.  I'm just asking questions to try to narrow down the cause of the error.  If I know the answer, I'll write one.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with that.  I think the `*` is what's messing it up.  I took out the pipe and got a `No such file or directory` error.  The example config has the pipe when it shows logresolvemerge, but it's also under the `coming from a pipe` section.  I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct usage does include the pipe at the end.  But awstats doesn't like the * at the end because it expects a number there as shown in the documentation.  For example: `LogFile="/var/awstats/tools/logresolvemerge.pl /var/log/webservers/web07/%YYYY-%MM/site.com/%DD-0-* |"`